# Time conversion in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, methods

I have this code to convert minutes into "hours:minutes" format.

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
    time = ""
    time_hours = minutes/60
    time_hours.round(0)
    time_minutes = minutes % 60
    time_minutes.round(2)
    time = "#{time_hours}:#{time_minutes}"
    return time
end

p time_conversion(360)
```

But my output is "6:0" when I want it to be "6:00". How could I clean this code up (simplify it) and also accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'd agree, however the titles of each are different enough. Depending on the user's search for this problem one or the other may come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def time_conversion(mins)
   hours, minutes = mins.divmod(60)
   sprintf('%d:%02d', hours, minutes)
end
```

or you can even make it a one-liner:

```
def time_conversion(mins)
   sprintf('%d:%02d', *mins.divmod(60))
end
```

The [`Numeric#divmod method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) returns the result of integer division and the result of the modulo operator at once. `'%d'` means insert an integer here. `'%02d'` means insert an integer and display at least two digits, filling in with 0s if necessary. You can do a lot more with [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) as well.

Comment: Could you explain why you used splat in the one-liner?

Comment: @Shawn `sprintf`'s first argument is a string, and then the rest of its arguments are a list of values to substitute into a string. `divmod` returns an array with two values. The `*` makes is so that the elements of the array are used as if they were passed directly to the method. I don't know the technical term for this though...

Comment: @Shawn See the 'Calling Methods' section of this article: https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/

Answer (score 1):

Use formatted output:

```
sprintf('%d:%02d', time_hours, time_minutes)
```

or the equivalent:

```
'%d:%02d' % [time_hours, time_minutes]
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this part: '%d:%02d'. Could you give more insight into this?

Comment: @Shawn [Reference manual of `sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).